# Transparent JTextField .setOpaque(false) doesn't work

Tags: java, swing

```
JTextField textbox1;
textbox1 = new JTextField();
textbox1.setBounds((549+x),(61+y),295,17);
textbox1.setOpaque(false);
Main.panel.add(textbox1);
```

I need a Textbox on top of an image to show the image underneath but still be able to be typed in. I've tried using the `textbox1.setOpaque(false)` method but it didn't change anything and didn't throw and error. Sorry if i didn't format the code properly I tried but I just don't use this site very often.

Comment: Could you add enough code to make this a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Is your textbox1 visible and can you type into it?

Comment: wait no sorry its not.

Answer (score 0):

set only the background of the text box to transparent

```
   setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

Use

```
    setOpaque(false);
```

Only when your text field has child components inside the textfield you want to make visible but not the textfield itself to avoid artifacts

The following example has a text field over a red circle.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class JunkStop{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("wakka");
        JPanel layout = new JPanel(null);   
        JPanel background = new JPanel(){
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillOval(100, 100, 200, 200);
            }

        };
        
        background.setOpaque(false);
        JTextField field = new JTextField("testing");
        field.setBackground( new Color(0, 0, 0, 0) );
        layout.add(field);
        layout.add(background);
        
        field.setSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        field.setBounds(100, 150, 200, 20);
        
        background.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);

        frame.setContentPane(layout);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added an example to your answer. Feel free to remove it.

Comment: I'm just glad to see the suggestion works. The more the merrier :)